# View should scroll if screen is too small

Tags: android, layout, view, scroll

I´ve got the following View that I tested using a 5 inches smartphone. Now I tested with a HTC Wildfire and have the problem, that I only see the first two buttons and the third is very very small. 
I want, if there is not enough space for the button to show, that the user can scroll to see the full button. What do I make wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/bg_ohne"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".NachdemSpiel" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Herzlichen Glückwunsch! Dein Highscore beträgt: " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPunkteNach"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="" />


    <Button
    android:id="@+id/nbtSenden"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nbtNochmal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPunkteNach"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/highscoresenden" />


   <Button
    android:id="@+id/nbtNochmal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nbtHauptmenu"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nbtSenden"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/nochmalspielen" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/nbtHauptmenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nbtNochmal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hauptmenue" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your layout in a ScrollView like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_ohne">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".NachdemSpiel" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Herzlichen Glückwunsch! Dein Highscore beträgt: " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPunkteNach"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/nbtSenden"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nbtNochmal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPunkteNach"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/highscoresenden" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/nbtNochmal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nbtHauptmenu"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nbtSenden"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/nochmalspielen" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nbtHauptmenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nbtNochmal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hauptmenue" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use a `ScrollView`, for this purpose. ScrollView can have only a child, so you have to wrap the whole `RelativeLayout`